# Git Repo Suddenly Giving Message error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1) error: cannot spawn stty: No such file or directory

Tags: git, github

I have a github repo that I've been working in for the last three months or so without a problem.

When github recently disabled access via username and password I changed the value of my `origin` remote to the structure:  `https://my_public_access_key@github.com/MyUsername/my-git-repo.git`.  For about two weeks pushing to this repo always worked fine.  But starting last week I suddenly began to get this error message:

```
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
error: cannot spawn stty: No such file or directory
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with the changes I made earlier but I am currently stuck and do not know how to get out of it.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: What credential manager did you set up for Git? If you didn't set one up, you get the default for your Git version, so what Git version (and host OS) are those?

Comment: @torek I don't think I setup a credential manager for get.  I just downloaded my personal access token from git and put it into my remote so I could continue doing pull requests.

Comment: "If you didn't set one up, you get the default for your Git version, so what Git version (and host OS) are those?"

Answer (score 0):

As it said [here](https://blog.katastros.com/a?ID=01550-e449e411-3420-42c1-81aa-cc7e81b0320d), this is because there is no user authentication information in the config file. You should add the authentication information of the user's identity in the config configuration file of `.git`. For example you can update the url for the origin like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://[userName]:[password]@github.com:YOURUSERNAME/IdeaTest.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```